# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

Tags: php, mysql

Acabei de subir minha aplicação para fazer um teste no servidor, sq sempre da o erro o seguinte erro

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/storage/5/71/81/cliente47/public_html/admin/filtros/tickets/EmAtendimentoTicket.php on line 34

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/storage/5/71/81/cliente47/public_html/admin/filtros/tickets/EmAtendimentoTicket.php on line 66
```

Porém no servidor local esse erro não acontece.

O erro parou de ser exibido após remover a seguinte linha:

```
and t.status =  'Em Atendimento'
```

Só que essa linha e responsável pelo filtro que essa pagina têm.

Arquivo:
[EmAtendimentoTicket.php]

```
<?php
    include './function/dbh.php';


    $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

    //Selecionar todos os usuario
    $sql = "
    SELECT
        T.id_ticket,
        T.assunto_ticket,
        T.open_ticket,
        T.id_cliente,
        T.status,
        C.id_cliente,
        C.nomeFantasia_cliente
    FROM
        ticket AS T
    INNER JOIN user_cliente AS C
    ON
        T.id_cliente = C.id_cliente and t.status =  'Em Atendimento'
    ORDER BY
        T.id_ticket ASC";

    //Executando query
    $ticket_cliente = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    //Contar total de usuarios
    $total_tickets = mysqli_num_rows($ticket_cliente );

    //Definir quantidade de clientes a serem exibidos por paginacao
    $quantidade_page = 6;

    //Calcular o numero de paginas necessarias para exibir todos os allClientes
    $num_paginas = ceil($total_tickets/$quantidade_page);

    //Calcular o inicio da visualizacao
    $inicio = ($quantidade_page*$pagina)-$quantidade_page;

    //Selecionar os clientes a serem apresentados
    $result_tickets = "
    SELECT
        T.id_ticket,
        T.assunto_ticket,
        T.open_ticket,
        T.id_cliente,
        T.status,
        C.id_cliente,
        C.nomeFantasia_cliente
    FROM
        ticket AS T
    INNER JOIN user_cliente AS C
    ON
        T.id_cliente = C.id_cliente and t.status =  'Em Atendimento'
    ORDER BY
        T.id_ticket ASC
    LIMIT 
        $quantidade_page OFFSET $inicio ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $result_tickets);
    $total_tickets = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Toda vez que aplicar mysqli_query pode usar assim `mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` e irá conseguir identificar qual foi o erro de sintaxe na query.

Comment: fiz a mudança, no servidor local não fez nd, sq no online deu o seguinte erro
    Unknown column 't.status' in 'on clause'

Comment: eu já apaguei  banco de dados e importei o meu local sq fica dando esse erro no servidor online

Comment: Coluna desconhecida 't.status' Você usou a letra "T" em minusculo, mas o correto conforme o AS é "T" em maisculo, o corretor seria `T.status`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Por nada, seja bem vindo a comunidade!